# Dir command unexpected behaviour

Tags: windows, terminal, directory, command, line

So if I run the command line from a folder (c:/users/USER/desktop/FOLDER1) and type:

```
dir /b /a-d *.txt *.bin
```

it will display the files of the folder with the extension *.txt or *.bin. Perfect.
Then, if I run the terminal from any other location (either its default or say, from another folder on another drive, e.g. D:\FOLDER2) and type the command:

```
dir /b /a-d "c:/users/USER/desktop/FOLDER1"
```

then it will display, correctly, a list of all the files in the FOLDER1.

BUT, lastly, if on the above command I add the parameters for the extensions, all hell brakes loose (running the terminal from the D:\FOLDER2):

```
dir /b /a-d *.txt *.bin "c:/users/USER/desktop/FOLDER1"
```

Then it displays the files from both the c:/users/USER/desktop/FOLDER1 AND D:\FOLDER2 (of the extensions asked and also some more random files with extensions not of the ones asked).

The only work around I've found is to cd to the drive I want:

`c:`

then cd to the folder:

```
cd c:/users/USER/desktop/FOLDER1
```

then run the actual command:

```
dir /b /a-d *.txt *.bin
```

And then it will display the correct files. But this is so troublesome and "ugly". I would expect a single command to do it.
What is happening? Am I doing something wrong? I've tried all possible combinations in the ordering of the parameters.

Comment: `dir /b /a-d *.txt *.bin "c:/users/USER/desktop/FOLDER1"` means "Show me all *.txt files in the current directory, all *.bin files in the current directory, and the complete contents of the `C:\users\USER\desktop\FOLDER1` directory. If you want to see *.txt files and *.bin files from `C:\users\USER\desktop\FOLDER1`, then say so: `dir /b /a-d C:\users\USER\desktop\FOLDER1\*.txt C:\users\USER\desktop\FOLDER1\*.bin`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was going crazy. 
So you can't condense it even more huh? like `dir /b /a-d C:\users\USER\desktop\FOLDER1\*.txt,*.bin`. Oh well, this will work fine.

Comment: Type `dir /?` to see what the `dir` command can do. It doesn't do much. Certainly doesn't have fancy SQL-like queries.